# How to properly configure 'sonata_type_collection' field in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

In a nutshell:

When I am using 'sonata_type_collection' in OneToMany relationship I have to specify the other side of the relation, which in the "create action" still does not exist and in  "update action" could be set, but it is also possible to specify entirely different parent.

More detailed explanation:

I am using Sonata Admin Bundle for the CRUD operations and lets say that I have only Post(id, title, content) and Tag(id, post_id, title) entities.
I would like to be able to add and remove tag entities while I am editing the Post entity, so I use 'sonata_type_collection' field.

This is the configureFormFields method from the PostAdmin class:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper                           
            ->add('title')
            ->add('content')
            ->add('tags', 'sonata_type_collection', array(), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table'
            ))  
        ))                
    ; 
}
```

The problem is that in the create form, when I add new tag I have to specify both post and title, but the Post still does not exist, so I am not able to add tags.
While I am editing the post I could add new tags, but for every one of them I have to explicitly set a post, and I am able for example to add a tag for entirely different post.

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Im not sure but how about to add prototype field set to true. At least when you are working with that kind of info that's what you do.

Comment: I don't know what is this field and how to set it. Could you tell me what do you mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to set the by_reference option to false.

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper                           
            ->add('title')
            ->add('content')
            ->add('tags', \Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\CollectionType::class, 
                          array('by_reference' => false),
                          array('edit' => 'inline',
                                'inline' => 'table'
                               )
                 );
}
```

[edit]
So it looks like the problem was coming from the Post entity which had to call tags' setPost() method from the addTag() method.

```
public function addTag($tag)
{
    $tag->setPost($this);
    $this->tags->add($tag);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I tried this before asking the question with no luck. Anyway, what is the purpose of this setting?

Comment: Quoting Symfony's doc, setting by_reference to false forces the setter to be called on the parent object, which seems appropriate in your case.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference
What do your entities look like ? Maybe you should check the setters that handle the relation.

Comment: The problem was in the addTag($tag) method of the Post entity. I had to explicitly set the post to the tag there by calling $tag->setPost($this);   If you add that to your answer I will be happy to accept it.